# Laravel Eloquent Database Validators Not Working In Slim 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, slim

I am developing in Slim 3. I decided for Eloquent as ORM and would like to use Illuminate validators in middleware to validate info that comes to my Controllers.

Validation rules that do not need to use database to validate work great but I am having trouble using database validators.

I do not get any errors it just does not pass when it should.

As far as I understand it I should create validator factory and then call make function. Example:

```
$v = $this->validatorFactory
       ->make($toCheck, $this->rules[$route], $this->messages);

if ($v->fails()) {....}
```

Since it works for all routes that do not need database I won't go here in any more detail. I think the problem is with how I add PressenceValidator to my factory.

I do it like this.

```
private function initiateValidatorFactory($dbConnectionSettings)
{
    $validatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory(
        new Translator(new FileLoader(new Filesystem(), "en"), "en"),
        null);

    $sqlConfig = $dbConnectionSettings['mysql'];

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $sqlConfig['host'] . ';port=' . $sqlConfig['port'] . ';dbname=' . $sqlConfig['database'];
    $connection = new Connection(
        new \PDO($dsn, $sqlConfig['username'], $sqlConfig['password']),
        $sqlConfig['database'],
        $sqlConfig['prefix']
    );
//        var_dump($connection->select('SELECT * FROM platform;'));
//        die();

    $resolver = new ConnectionResolver(['mysql' =>  $connection]);

//        var_dump($resolver->hasConnection('mysql'));
//        die();

//        var_dump($resolver->connection('mysql'));
//        die();

    $verifier = new DatabasePresenceVerifier($resolver);
//        $verifier->setConnection('mysql');

    $validatorFactory->setPresenceVerifier($verifier);

    $this->validatorFactory = $validatorFactory;
}
```

I would like to note that this raw SQL query which is commented out works at that point. That is why I don't think problem is with Connection class.

Notice how I created almost dummy FileLoader but I don't think I need it for my use case (or I might I am not sure).

All commented out checks look ok.

I tried googling and saw that people mention something about "booting eloquent". I tried to find where I could do that in my code but wasn't successful.

Last thing is I am missing is how I write my rules. Example rule is this:

```
'platformid' => 'exists:mysql.platform,platformid'
```

PS don't ask why we have column "platformid" in table "platform" =).

I am using illuminate/validation 5.5 and illuminate/database 5.5.

Thank you for your time and any help you can provide in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow figured it out. It is hacky but I think I can live with it now. I don't quite understand why this approach works but it does.

So I have database service provider like this:

```
$capsule = new Manager();

    ////////CONFIGURE MYSQL\\\\\\\
    $sqlConfig = $pimple['settings']['db']['mysql'];
    $capsule->addConnection([
        'driver'    => $sqlConfig['driver'],
        'host'      => $sqlConfig['host'],
        'database'  => $sqlConfig['database'],
        'username'  => $sqlConfig['username'],
        'password'  => $sqlConfig['password'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ], $this->connectionName);
....
....
$pimple['db'] = function ($c) use ($capsule) {
        return $capsule;
    };
```

I call that in my dependencies.php

Then when I come to routes I do this:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$validatorMiddleware = new \....\Middleware\BaseMiddleware($container->get('db'));
```

I changed my middleware init to this

```
private function initiateValidatorFactory($dbConnectionSettings)
{
    $validatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory(
        new Translator(new FileLoader(new Filesystem(), "en"), "en"),
        null);

    $resolver = new ConnectionResolver(['mysql' =>  $dbConnectionSettings->getConnection('mysql')]);

    $verifier = new DatabasePresenceVerifier($resolver);

    $validatorFactory->setPresenceVerifier($verifier);

    $this->validatorFactory = $validatorFactory;
}
```

Notice how my variables don't make sense any more but you will figure it out how to make it nicer and stuff. (me included). Most important thing is this works somehow. I know it is hacky. If you wish to post an answer that does not include hacks please do =).